# print byte from number in awk

Tags: awk, byte

I can print a byte from a string literal like:
`awk 'BEGIN {print "\001"}' | cat -v`

But I need to print a byte of the result of a bitwise OR.
So how can I print a byte from a number?

Gawk is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `%c` printf format specifier, I think:

```
$ mawk 'BEGIN {printf "%c\n", 3}' | cat -v
^C

$ LC_CTYPE=C gawk 'BEGIN {printf "%c\n", or(1,2)}' | cat -v
^C
```

The `LC_CTYPE=C` is probably only necessary with GNU awk, if your values may exceed a single byte in a locale that supports multi-byte characters.